# How to transfer session php data from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am working with some PHP Session and Array data that I am filtering into JS in a Laravel 4 view.  Currently, the php ooks like this in the javascript portion.

```
<?php $number_of_posts = 7; ?>;
    <?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = isset($_SESSION['posts_start']) ? $_SESSION['posts_start'] : $number_of_posts; ?>;

    var start = {{ Session::get('posts_start', 7) }};
    var initialPosts = <?php echo Fanfollow::follows_json(Auth::user()->get()->id,0, $_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>;
    var desiredPosts = <?php echo $number_of_posts; ?>;
```

This works fine, however I would like to move my javascript to an external js file, as opposed to mixing the PHP and JS.

My question is, how do I take the PHP above and make accessible with js without using PHP directly in the js.

An example would be using an HTML hidden input in the view like so:

```
<input type="hidden" id="num_posts" name="num_posts" value="{{$number_of_posts}}">
```

and then pulling it using js:

```
var number_posts = $('#num_posts').val();
```

Can something similar be done for the code I have above? (the session and array data?)

Comment: Why would being previously stored in a session or array make a difference to your ability to print it into the HTML source?

Comment: You should probably add a jQuery tag to the question.

Comment: There is no reason to use isset($_SESSION[]) while inside of Laravel. You should be using Session::has('key_here') if you want to check if a Session data exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the value from your template system

```
<script>
var number_posts = {{$number_of_posts}};
</script>
```

And any Javascript code will use `number_posts` should be after the code above.

Answer (score 0):

if you really, really really want to do this you can store the session data in

```
window.YOUR_SESSION_VARIABLE
```

and call ii in your external js file.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with ajax. I created get_session.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo json_encode($_SESSION);
```

And then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_session.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        // do stuff with session data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can place your javascript/php mix like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.php"></script>
```